# Replacing AppSettings with KeyVault values - timing question

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I am coding a .NET Core 6 Web API and trying to convert to using key vaults.  I'm calling `AddAzureKeyVault` in my `CreateAppConfiguration` section BUT I need the adjusted database connection string inside `Startup.cs`'s `ConfigureServices` method since that's where we are setting up the services (including SQL Server).  Even though I've already past the breakpoint in `AddAzureKeyVault` when I stop inside `ConfigurationServices` I am seeing the original dummy values from my `appsettings` file.  Later, in my controller methods they are nicely overlaid on top of my `appsettings` as you would expect.

Currently, I'm loading the keyvault value there just to make it work, but there must be some better way so that the keyvault values get loaded sooner - is there?  Where else can I put it?

From Program.cs

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
               {
                   ...
                   config.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(vaultUrl), credential, new PrefixKeyVaultSecretManager("KVTest"));
               })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

From Startup.cs

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //======================= new key vault stuff ===========================
            // The key vault values have NOT been applied yet, so we need to manually grab the DB conn string here
            var connString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("InformCoreDbContext");
            //^^ I see the dummy string from the appsettings file here

            //======================= horrible kludge ===============================
            // If I open the keyvault and grab the conn string that works, but
            // I shouldn't have to do this here since I'm overloading them at some point
            connString = temporaryMachinationsToGrabKeyVaultConnString();
                    
            services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<ICAdminContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(connString,
              sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
              {
                  sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
              }));
```

Note:  I did read [how-to-get-azure-keyvault-key-inside-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004288/net-core-6-minimal-hosting-model-how-to-get-azure-keyvault-key-inside-config), but that solution didn't work for me .  The config object inside the extension method still doesn't have the keyvault entries loaded.

Comment: Not relevant to .NET Core, but I've used ConfigurationBuilders for .NET Framework with great success. https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders/blob/main/docs/KeyValueConfigBuilders.md

Answer (score 0):

Check the below workaround to override the values of App Settings with Azure Key Vault.
Thanks @Wouter for the explanation.

- Initially created .NET 6 Web API and published to Azure.

***My appsettings.json***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "managedinstance": "Wonderland",
  "KeyVaultName": "harshithakeyvault",
  "Secrets": {
    "One": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(Secreturi=[uri to secret copied from Azure blade])"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

***Initial App Settings Value from local***

[image]

- Create Managed Identity, give the name same as  deployed `Azure App Service` name.
- In Azure Portal, create a `KeyVault`,give access rights to the key vault.
- Create `Access policy` => Select `Get,List` permissions => search for the `principal`
  **`The principal name will be same as the App service name`** => `Review + create`

[image]

- Create a New Secret in Azure Key vault,
  `Secrets` => `Generate/Import`.

[image]

- In the deployed Azure App, make sure the system Identity status is `on`.
- In Azure App settings add the key with the name same as Secret in the `Azure KeyVault`.

Copy the  `Secret Identifier` in the KeyVault Secret.

[image]

Replace the `uri` with the `Secret Identifier` in the KeyVault Secret.
[image]

***My Program.cs***

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
      new Uri($"https://{builder.Configuration["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
      new DefaultAzureCredential());
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

***In Controller***

```cs
 private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
 public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
 public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
 {
     return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
     {
         Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
         TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
         Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)],

         Myvalues = Configuration.GetSection("managedinstance").Value
     })
     .ToArray();
 }
```

***.csproj file***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***Final Output - Value from KeyVault***
[image]

**References taken from [Link](https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/how-to-use-keyvault-to-override-appsettings-in-azure-152feae1a4c0)**