# How to skip setting up Azure KeyVault in development environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-keyvault

I'm getting a token from Azure KeyVault. I setup the keyvault in Program.cs file. It works as long as the Azure account in Visual Studio got access. obviously once that account doesn't have access, an error is thrown.

How do I skip setting up the key vault in case it's development env AND get token value from appsettings.json? I don't want the app to fail because the account is not authorized and also get token value provided by the user in appsettings.json.

```
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })

      .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
      {
        var builtConfig = config.Build();
        var vaultConfigSection = builtConfig.GetSection("AzureOne");
        var vaultUri = vaultConfigSection.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultUri");
        var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
      });
    }
```

my appsettings.json look like this

```
{
  "EndPoints": {
    "EndpointOne": "https://awesome.net"
  },
  "AzureOne": {
    "TokenToBeUsedInDev": "4234-fake-234234-fake",
    "KeyVaultUri": "https://myKeyVaultName.vault.azure.net/"
  },
}
```

I'm using .NET 5

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.json` file ?

Comment: What is the .Net Core version you are using?

Comment: I added them! I'm using .net 5

Comment: Are you getting any error with the above code ?

Comment: .Net 5 is out of support, recommend you to use .Net 6

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get Azure KeyVault token value from `appsettings.json`.It works for both Azure KeyVault secrets and local `appsettings.json`

```cs
using Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KVLocalTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                     {
                         var builtConfig = config.Build();                        
                         var vaultConfigSection = builtConfig.GetSection("AzureOne");
                         var vaultUri = vaultConfigSection.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultUri");
                         config.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(vaultConfigSection.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultUri")),
      new DefaultAzureCredential());                     

    }
}
```

***Retrieve token in Controller and display in `.cshtml`***
***`HomeController.cs`***

```cs
using KVLocalTest.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KVLocalTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var vaultConfigSection = Configuration.GetSection("AzureOne");
            ViewBag.TokenLocal =  vaultConfigSection.GetValue<string>("TokenToBeUsedInDev");
            return View();
        }  
    }
}
```

***.cshtml***

```cs
<h2>@ViewBag.TokenLocal</h2>
```

***Output***

[image]

***Update***

```cs
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
var isDevelopment = environment == Environments.Development;

if (!isDevelopment)
{
  var vaultConfigSection = builtConfig.GetSection("AzureOne");
  config.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(vaultConfigSection.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultUri")),
       new DefaultAzureCredential());
}
```

Comment: This won't let Program.cs run because the account doesn't have access to KeyVault. That's my question, how to skip connecting to KeyVault if the developer doesn't have access to KeyVault.

Comment: Please check the update in the Answer.

Comment: @jsnoobie Please refer this [Document](https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/how-to-use-keyvault-to-override-appsettings-in-azure-152feae1a4c0) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020057/replacing-appsettings-with-keyvault-values-timing-question/74301563#74301563) to get access to KeyVault.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a user managed identity in Azure. Then you assign that identity to access keyvault. You could use that identity in your code to get an access token and use it in your dev environment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/authentication

Comment: The app is actually running in Azure and got an identity that can access the KeyVault. However, it's not clear how to use that identity in my code to get an access token and use it in your dev environment. I read the docs but they are terrible! Any better places to look?